# キューで関数enqueueとdequeueを行った時の配列内は、どのようになるのですか？

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 4
void enquene(char *Q,char x);
char dequeue(char *Q);
void initialize(char *Q);
int empty(char *Q);
int head=0;
int tail=0;
int number=0;
void enqueue(char *Q,char x){
    if(number<MAX){
        number++;
        tail=(tail%MAX)+1;
        Q[tail]=x;
    }
    else{
        printf("Queue Q is overflows.\n");
    }
}
char dequeue(char *Q){
    if(number>0){
        number--;
        head=(head%MAX)+1;
        return(Q[head]);
    }
    else{
        printf("Queue Q is empty.\n");
        return('0');
    }
}
void initialize(char *Q){
    int i;
    head=0;
    tail=0;
    number=0;
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        Q[i]='\0';
    }
}
int empty(char *Q){
    if(number==0){
        return(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
int main(void){
    char x;
    char Q[MAX];
    enqueue(Q,'a');
    enqueue(Q,'b');
    enqueue(Q,'c');
    x=dequeue(Q);
    x=dequeue(Q);
    enqueue(Q,'d');
    x=dequeue(Q);
    enqueue(Q,'e');
    while(!empty(Q)){
        printf("%c",dequeue(Q));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: その「アルゴリズムの本」は何かというのと、それの何処が判らなかったかも具体的に記述してみてください。まあこの辺の記事が参考になるかと思われますが。[【C言語/データ構造】スタックとキューの配列での実装方法](https://daeudaeu.com/stack_queue/), [スタックとキューを極める！ 〜 考え方と使い所を特集 〜](https://qiita.com/drken/items/6a95b57d2e374a3d3292), [待ち行列，キュー(queue)](http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/~yamada/ap/queue.html)

Comment: 質問本文をきちんと推敲してください。

Answer (score 0):

まず、main関数内のキュー/エンキュー処理毎のあるべきキューの中身を整理すると以下のものです。
[image: キュー/エンキュー処理毎のあるべきキューの中身]
 したがって、出力として想定しているのは「de」になると思いますが、想定通りの出力ができなかったため質問を記述したという認識です。
 想定通りの出力ができなかった理由としては、Q[tail]、Q[head]で配列外参照をしたため想定通りにならなかったと思います。
 main内の処理の提示されたソースコードにおけるdequeueとenqueue実行後のtailとheadの値を整理すると以下の通りです。
[image: tailとheadの値]
 したがって配列のサイズは4で、配列はQ[0]～Q[3]なのですが、head・tailがそれぞれ4になることがあり配列外参照をしていることがわかると思います。
　これは「tail=(tail%MAX)+1;」「head=(head%MAX)+1;」部分の誤りによるためです。
　それぞれ「tail=((tail+1)%MAX);」「head=((head+1)%MAX);」に修正すれば想定通りの結果になると思われます。